# how to start with laravel/ui - npm run dev dosn't work

Tags: laravel

I'm newbie into laravel. I'made clean laravel install with laravel/ui. I have to touch src/index.js to go forward. What next? Run npm run dev dosn't make any files?

Answer (score 0):

First, add laravel/ui to your app

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Then swap the front-end scaffolding to vue.

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

--auth should build authentication functionalities (register, login, logout)

Run

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

At least, migrate:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Take a look in the public folder; the generated code should be there.
Also, check the mix-manifest.json

Laravel 7 introduced the laravel/ui package to create authentication scaffolding, but with the latest Laravel 8 version, a new laravel/jetstream package is introduced.
Take a look in this [link](https://www.techiediaries.com/laravel-8-auth-scaffolding-jetstream-inertiajs-livewire/#:%7E:text=Laravel%208%20Jetstream%20is%20a,Sanctum%2C%20and%20optional%20team%20management.).